# Convert list of strings to proper directory names with backslash

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, backslash

I have a list of strings that have spaces in them. I want to change every string so that there's a backslash before the spaces so that they can be used as directory names. What's a short way to do this, possibly with list comprehension or something?

example with longer code:

```
directories = []
for s in schools:
    words = s.split(' ')
    directory = '\\ '.join(words)
    directories.append(directory)
```

Comment: Hello, Jake - not quite following.  Would you please post an example of input/output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.replace()`, which is going to be much more efficient than splitting and re-joining. If you have a list, a list comprehension can do this for every string in the list:

```
escaped = [s.replace(' ', r'\ ') for s in list_of_strings]
```

Comment: Thanks, what does the 'r' do though?

Comment: @Jake: it's a raw string literal, so I don't have to escape the backslash. You can also use `'\\ '`.

Comment: Thanks going to accept this answer once it allows :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path.join` because it return paths that supports cross platform. This way is the preferred way of joining directory paths

```
import os
directories = [os.path.join(s.split(' ')) for s in schools]
```